# Azure traffic manager cname

Tags: azure, azure-traffic-manager

Hi I have too webapps in 2 different regions

webapp1.azurewebsites.net
webapp2.azurewebsites.net

webapp1.azurewebsites.net has a custom domain name (www.myrealdomainname.com) associated with it and is mapped via A Record on my providers dns record.

I have also added a cname record to webapp1.azurewebsites.net like this - www.myrealdomainname.com to mywebapp.trafficmanager.net

My question is when I visit www.myrealdomainname.com it doesnt go through traffic manager. Why is this? The dashboard on the portal shows nothing.

Also if I disable webapp1.azurewebsites.net leaving only webapp2.azurewebsites.net, and visit www.myrealdomainname.com it shows me content from webapp1.azurewebsites.net - again it doesnt go through traffic manager.

Is this because of the A record?

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely the case. I do not understand why you have some DNS records pointing directly at one of the apps anyway if you are using Traffic Manager. Just point all records to Traffic Manager and configure it to distribute your traffic as you need.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-traffic-manager-custom-domain-name/

A quote from there: "When your website is configured as a Traffic Manager endpoint, you will use the .trafficmanager.net address when creating DNS records. You can only use CNAME records with Traffic Manager"